# Duda con expresion Regular en Node JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```
          //Para traer el Id del estudiante , este me funciona perfectamente
            var idPatt ="[0-9]+";
            var patt = new RegExp("/estudiante/id/"+ idPatt);

            //Para traer el nombre del estudiante
            //Creo que acá estoy definiendo mal esto, la verdad no se como 

            var nombre="[A-Za-z]+";
            urlpornombre =new RegExp("/estudiante/name/"+ nombre);



            if(patt.test(req.url)){
                patt = new RegExp(idPatt);
                var id = patt.exec(req.url);
                st.getId(req, resp,id);

            }else if(urlpornombre.test(req.url)){
                urlpornombre = new RegExp(nombre);
                var name = urlpornombre.exec(req.url);
                st.getName(req, resp,name);

            }           
            else{
                httpMsgs.show404(req,resp);
            }
```

Cuando traigo el id del estudiante me lo trae muy bien, pero cuando intento traer el nombre del estudiante se me revienta, yo creo que el problema es debido a la expresión regular que estoy utilizando puesto que no se muy bien como hacerlo para que me reciba cadenas tanto mayuscular y minusculas, que por ejemplo al momento de yo decirle: localhost:3000/estudiante/name/Juan, me muestre todos los estudiantes que empiezan por Juan.

Comment: Existe [express](http://expressjs.com/es/) para el manejo de rutas en node.